# import SimpleCV works in one directory, but fails in another

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to use SimpleCV in python 2.7 x64. When I run "import SimpleCV" command with python in "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages" directory - all works. But if I want to do it in, for example, home (~) directory I have an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-      packages/SimpleCV/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from SimpleCV.base import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SimpleCV/base.py", line 176, in <module>
    def npArray2cvMat(inputMat, dataType=cv.CV_32FC1):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_32FC1'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: that happens sometimes because one of your user modules is called `cv.py` (sounds strange here, though). Can you list the contents of your home directory?

Comment: AndroidStudioProjects Mac   Pictures  ideepcolor
Applications  Makefile  Projects  main.c
BrawlhallaReplays Makefile.pre  Public   opencv
Desktop   Misc   Python   opencv_contrib
Documents  Modules   Untitled.ipynb  pyconfig.h
Downloads  Movies   Untitled1.ipynb  scikit_learn_data
Grammar   Music   VirtualBox VMs
Himawari.Kt  Objects   config.log
Library   Parser   config.status

Comment: Sorry for this format

Comment: wrong lead. I'd vouch for an incompatibility between `cv` and `SimpleCV` versions. (btw you can [edit] your question when someone comments, instead of dumping the result in the comments. Here it doesn't matter: that's not the issue)

Comment: As I know SimpleCV can use only opencv2 version (not opencv3) and I have installed both of it.

Comment: so I think you should uninstall opencv3 if you don't need it. http://answers.opencv.org/question/64693/can-i-use-cvcreatemat2-1-cvcv_32fc1-in-opencv-300/%2Fanswers.opencv.org%2Fquestion%2F64693%2Fcan-i-use-cvcreatemat2-1-cvcv_32fc1-in-opencv-300%2F&usg=AFQjCNHB1l1QEkbzAQq2umPVMMwET9US7A